# What are the general solutions of the Diophantine equation $ ax+by+cxy+d=0 $

Tags: arithmetic, diophantine-equations

Does the diophantine equation $$ ax+by+cxy+d=0 $$ always have solutions ?

Comment: It depends on $a,b,c,d$. For example, if $a=b=c=2$ and $d=3$, there is no solution (otherwise you would have $2(x+y+xy+1)+1=0$).

Comment: @Crostul is there a general study of this equation ?

Comment: I don't think so. Why are you interested in this equation? Usually "interesting" equations have more indeterminates than parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume $c \ne 0$.  Write the equation as
$$ (cx + b) (cy + a) = ab - cd $$
So there are integer solutions iff you can factor $ab - cd$ into factors congruent to $a$ and $b$ mod $c$.

Comment: Thank you very much for this handy trick @Robert :) It was useful for my case $-10^5x-10^5y+xy=0$